# arm_navigation_msgs

Tags: ros, object-manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey WG folk, I noticed a good deal of activity in wg-ros-pkg that involves converting packages to use arm_navigation_msgs. Where is arm_navigation_msgs? It doesn't show up in ros_wiki_docs, and I've had no luck looking through the available source.

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10594/arm_navigation_msgs/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2011-07-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sean,

Almost all of the activity of wg-ros-pkg these days is getting ready for the electric release, and the refactoring we're doing for arm_navigation is a big part of that.  We're also increasingly moving away from shoving everything into wg-ros-pkg to making projects on kforge.ros.org that may have one or more associated repositories.  For electric we're collapsing the core stacks associated with arm_navigation into two stacks - arm_navigation and arm_navigation_experimental.  These stacks are now in separate mercurial repos in the Arm Navigation project: https://kforge.ros.org/project/armnavigation/ .  The arm navigation stack has the new arm_navigation_msgs package - you can check out the very latest and greatest of these stacks by overlaying the following using rosinstall:

- hg: {local-name: stacks/arm_navigation, uri: 'https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/armnavigation',
  version: arm_navigation_metrics}
- hg: {local-name: stacks/arm_navigation_experimental, uri: 'https://kforge.ros.org/armnavigation/experimental',
  version: arm_navigation_metrics}

The refactoring we've been doing has not yet been released into the unstable debs but that should be happening very soon - for now if you want to check it out you'll have to pull from source.  But I will warn you that things are very unstable - things should settle down soon as we've got an impending feature freeze.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3